# Method and Constructor<?> both inherit from Member, both having a getExceptionTypes() method. How to avoid code duplication in this scenario?

Tags: java, oop, refactoring, code-duplication

I have both these methods in my code base, which I'd like to merge in some way to avoid code duplication:

```
protected IJavaType[] getExceptionTypes(Method method) {
    Class<?>[] declaredExceptions = method.getExceptionTypes();

    IJavaType[] exceptions = new IJavaType[declaredExceptions.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < declaredExceptions.length; i++) {
        exceptions[i] = getType(declaredExceptions[i]);
    }

    return exceptions;
}

protected IJavaType[] getExceptionTypes(Constructor<?> c) {
    Class<?>[] declaredExceptions = c.getExceptionTypes();

    IJavaType[] exceptions = new IJavaType[declaredExceptions.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < declaredExceptions.length; i++) {
        exceptions[i] = getType(declaredExceptions[i]);
    }

    return exceptions;
}
```

Is there any way to factor out the code repetition (other than using subclassing with template pattern)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about simply:

```
private IJavaType[] getExceptionTypes(Class<?>[] declaredExceptions) {
    IJavaType[] exceptions = new IJavaType[declaredExceptions.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < declaredExceptions.length; i++) {
        exceptions[i] = getType(declaredExceptions[i]);
    }

    return exceptions;
}

protected IJavaType[] getExceptionTypes(Method method) {
    return getExceptionTypes(method.getExceptionTypes());
}

protected IJavaType[] getExceptionTypes(Constructor<?> c) {
    return getExceptionTypes(c.getExceptionTypes());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well you can extract *most* of it fairly easily:

```
protected IJavaType[] getExceptionTypes(Method method) {
    return getExceptionTypesImpl(method.getExceptionTypes());
}

protected IJavaType[] getExceptionTypes(Constructor<?> c) {
    return getExceptionTypesImpl(c.getExceptionTypes());    
}

private void getExceptionTypesImpl(Class<?>[] declaredExceptions) {
    IJavaType[] exceptions = new IJavaType[declaredExceptions.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < declaredExceptions.length; i++) {
        exceptions[i] = getType(declaredExceptions[i]);
    }

    return exceptions;
}
```